# How can leaflet pop-up labels be formatted in R?

Tags: r, popup, format, leaflet

I have a dataframe:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/51j3hh9urwjudu2/Agents.csv?dl=0

Using this, I can create a leaflet map using this code:

```
map = leaflet() %>%

  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles

  addCircles(lng = agents$longitude, lat = agents$latitude, 
             popup=paste("Agent:", agents$Agent, "<br>",
                         "Satisfaction:", agents$Satisfaction, "<br>", 
                         "No. Customers:", agents$Customers, "<br>",
                         "Colour Ref:", agents$Colour), 
             radius = agents$Customers * 10,
             color = agents$Colour,
             stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.5)
```

which looks like this:

[image]

Now, I would like to:

have the first line in bold font (in this case 'Agent 4'). I have tried inserting:

```
"", agents$Agent, font = 2 "<br>",
```

but this does not work.

I would also like to tab 'Medium', '4200' and 'green' so that they are all in line with each other and so easier to read.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: You can customize labels with CSS (see https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/popups.html).

Answer (score 9):

I find it easier to create a new variable in the data frame for the popup text.

Here is an example.

```
agents$popup_text <- 
  paste0('<strong>', agents$Agent, '</strong>',
         '<br/>', 'Satisfaction: ', '<strong>', agents$Satisfaction, '</strong>', ' ') %>% 
  lapply(htmltools::HTML)
```